# Sheets: Uncaught TypeError: google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(...).is not a function

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications

[image]

I have the following in an apps script template body:

```
    <script>

    function getConversations() {
       var jsonRow = <?= row ?>; //PASSED IN JSON
       console.log('row');
       var myObj = JSON.parse(jsonRow);
           console.log(myObj['CONVERSATION'].split('|'));

        return myObj['CONVERSATION'].split('|'); // array of texts

    };

            $(function() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList)
            .getConversations();

    });

           function buildOptionList(options) {
        var list = $('#optionList');
        //     alert('hi');
        //     https://tutorialzine.com/2010/11/jquery-data-method
        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            console.log(options[i]);
            list.append('<option value="' + options[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
        }
    };



    </script>
```

the getConversations functions is working as expected and I can see the correct output in the console. When I add the rest of the code I get the error in the title. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: At ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList).getConversations()``, ``getConversations()`` is required to be a function of GAS side. The error indicates that ``getConversations()`` was not found in GAS. The official document is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). In your case, do you want to send the value of ``row`` from GAS to ``getConversations()`` in HTNM side by ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList).getConversations()``?

Comment: I noticed a spelling miss just now. "HTNM" was "HTML". I'm sorry.

Comment: That is correct , I would like the returned result from getConversations() (an array) to be the input  ("options") into buildOptionList().

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood what you want to do, I apologize. At that time, can you provide more information? I would like to modify the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve a value from `getConversations()` at `buildOptionList()`.
- `row` of `var jsonRow = <?= row ?>` is created at GAS side.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### HTML side:

- In this modification, `getConversations()` is used at GAS side and return `myObj['CONVERSATION'].split('|')`. So please remove `getConversations()`, because this is not used in this modification.
- Using `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildOptionList).getConversations()`, `getConversations()` at GAS side is run and the value is sent to `buildOptionList()`.

#### GAS side:

Please put the following script in the script of GAS side.

```
function getConversations() {
  var myObj = {CONVERSATION: "sample1|sample2|sample3"}; // This is a sample value. Because I'm not sure about row you use.
  return myObj['CONVERSATION'].split('|');
}
```

- Here, I'm not sure about `row`. So from your script, I imaged the sample value and used it. Please replace `myObj` to yours.
- Value created at `getConversations()` is sent to `buildOptionList(options)`. And you can retrieve the value as `options`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized I had made an error and did not need google.script.run.withSuccessHandler at all , as I wanted to process the object only on the HTML side. I ended up using:

```
    <script>


    function getConversations() {
       var jsonRow = <?= row ?>; //PASSED IN JSON
       console.log('row');
       var myObj = JSON.parse(jsonRow);
           console.log(myObj['CONVERSATION'].split('|'));

        return myObj['CONVERSATION'].split('|'); // array of texts

    };

           function buildOptionList(options) {
        var list = $('#optionList');

        list.empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
            console.log(options[i]);
            list.append('<option value="' + options[i].toLowerCase() + '">' + options[i] + '</option>');
        }
    };

    (function (){buildOptionList(getConversations())}());
```